# Spotfire create growth calculated column

Tags: spotfire

I am totally new at spotfire environtment. I want to create new calculated column as growth of the other column. Here is my data :

```
Item  ||  Date       || Value  || Growth
A     ||  12/12/2014 || 102    || 
A     ||  13/12/2014 || 121    || 19
B     ||  12/12/2014 || 141    || 
B     ||  13/12/2014 || 111    || -30
```

How to create Growth column with custom expression?

I already get some sample code that solve the similar problem. But, i still got an error.

first of all i create hierarchy named Hirarki that include Item and Date.
then i create this custom expression, but there's an error said that `"couldnt find hierachy : 'Hirarki'"`

```
sum([value]) OVER (intersect(parent([Axis.Hirarki]),[Axis.Hirarki])) - sum([value]) OVER (intersect(parent([Axis.Hirarki]),previous([Axis.Hirarki])))
```

Why spotfire couldnt find my hierarchy?

Thank you,
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think this formula calculates what you need

```
Sum([Value]) OVER ([Item],[Date]) - Sum([Value]) OVER (Intersect([Item],Previous([Date])))
```